# Get Bing search results in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, bing

I am trying to make a chatbot that can get Bing search results using Python. I've tried many websites, but they all use old Python 2 code or Google. I am currently in China and cannot access YouTube, Google, or anything else related to Google (Can't use Azure and Microsoft Docs either). I want the results to be like this:

```
This is the title
https://this-is-the-link.com

This is the second title
https://this-is-the-second-link.com
```

Code

```
import requests
import bs4
import re
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.bing.com/search?q=programming")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
links = soup.findAll("a")
for link in links:
    print(link["href"])
```

And it gives me

```
/?FORM=Z9FD1
javascript:void(0);
javascript:void(0);
/rewards/dashboard
/rewards/dashboard
javascript:void(0);
/?scope=web&FORM=HDRSC1
/images/search?q=programming&FORM=HDRSC2
/videos/search?q=programming&FORM=HDRSC3
/maps?q=programming&FORM=HDRSC4
/news/search?q=programming&FORM=HDRSC6
/shop?q=programming&FORM=SHOPTB
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=521839
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=246338
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=868922
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=286759
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=617297
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated (I'm using Python 3.6.9 on Ubuntu)

Comment: Welcome. Have you tried to do some research, maybe some code already written?

Comment: I've tried BeautifulSoup, but it doesn't really work. It just shows me some microsoft.com's and weibo.com's and thats it

Comment: It will be great to share your efforts.

Comment: What have you tried to do? It's important to explain what you have tried, current code that may not be executing expected results or some effort into your end goal. You might get downvoted because the lack of code which might come across as "expecting others to do the work"

Comment: Welcome! I don't recommend web scraping large vendors. More than likely they have preventative measures against it. Instead, look for available APIs, which most vendors provide (especially if it is a legitimate operation), to do what you're trying to do. A quick online search yielded their [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices-bingsearch/bing-web-api-v7-reference) for just that. And the [pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/search-api/) is free for a POC size project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, code you've written working properly, problem is in HTTP request headers. By default `urllib` use `Python-urllib/{version}` as `User-Agent` header value, which makes easy for website to recognize your request as automatically generated. To avoid this, you should use custom value which can be achieved passing [`Request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request) object as first parameter of `urlopen()`:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode, urlunparse
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

query = "programming"
url = urlunparse(("https", "www.bing.com", "/search", "", urlencode({"q": query}), ""))
custom_user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"
req = Request(url, headers={"User-Agent": custom_user_agent})
page = urlopen(req)
# Further code I've left unmodified
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
links = soup.findAll("a")
for link in links:
    print(link["href"])
```

*P.S. Take a look on comment left by @edd under your question.*

Comment: It works! I managed to get an API key and it successfully read all the search results. Thanks a LOT!